# Xcode 12 failed to emit precompiled header

Tags: ios, flutter

After update flutter SDK to 2.2.2 getting this error

"""failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/ravi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqlnymlzrsrujjbomhlcxxrcddlf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_1JOPSKUR82JXR-clang_13CYFACM79D1B.pch' for bridging header '/Users/ravi/Documents/ripsey_mobile_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h"""